# How to read multiple Atoms objects from a single file using ASE

Tags: atomic-simulation-environment

I am trying to read Atoms objects from the file "data.txt", which contains multiple configurations. Each configuration has a different cell.

```
a = ase.io.read('data.txt', format = 'vasp')
```

But my code only reads the first configuration in the file.

What do I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add `index=':'`:

```
images = ase.io.read('data.txt', format = 'vasp', index=':')
```

Comment: Thank you. It happened that my collaborator directly copied the data from a pdf file. The data had different delimiter, so index=':' wasn't working. Should always check the data file first.